# Calling Overload Methods

Tags: string, methods, char, int, overflow

I can't seem to make this work let alone compile and I am at loss at how to fix it. My teacher gave us the following code (simplified for question's sake):

```
public static void doing1(String s) {
    // add code here
}

public static void doing2(char start, char end) {
    // add code here
}

public static int doing3(int num) {
    // add code here
}

public static void doing4(Scanner keyboard) {
    // add code here
}
```

I know what needs to go in each method (the work I mean) I just don't know how to print it out in the main method. We cannot change the code given to us, only add to it.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean method overloads?

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice the typo. I meant 'overloads'. Thank you for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

Overloading a method means having the same method name but the method signature (the parameters passed in) is different.  So, what you have isn't actually an overload, it is for unique methods because they all have different names.  As far as not compiling... what you posted looks fine - perhaps you have an error above or below that code.  I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
public static void doing(String s) {
    // add code here
}

public static void doing(char start, char end) {
    // add code here
}

public static int doing(int num) {
    // add code here
}

public static void doing(Scanner keyboard) {
    // add code here
}
```

Here's a [reference on overloads](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx) from the almighty John Skeet

Comment: How would one print what each method does in the main method then, if these are all viable methods?

Comment: just call them from main using the different overloads.  You didn't say what language so pseudo code is Console.Out.Writeline(Doing("string"));  Console.Out.Writeline(Doing(1).ToString());